# 3D Interpolation in SciPy

Tags: python, 3d, grid, scipy, interpolation

I have 3D data on an array of shape `[544, 256, 256]`. At each grid point, there is a value of a function, say `F(x,y,z)`. I need to interpolate between gridpoints as part of a Runge-Kutta 4th order scheme.

For example, I want to be able to evaluate

```
k2 = hf(x_n + h/2, y_n + k1/2, z_n +j1/2).
```

Call values such as `x_n + h/2` or `y_n + k1/2` are likely to fall between gridpoints.
I've had a look at the `scipy.interpolate` package and haven't been able to find a function that works for me (or I haven't been able to get it to work).

Comment: `scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator` looks like what you need.

Comment: Many  thanks, I'm going to have a look at that.